# Can the Confidential Client facility be used to expose an adapter externally in MobileFirst 8?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I need to make some of my MFP 8 Adapters available to third-party (non-MobileFirst) clients. Is this possible in production using Confidential Clients? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can read more about the implementation in the following tutorial

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/confidential-clients/

> Clients that do not use the MobileFirst client SDK can also request protected resources, by acting as a confidential client.